# Add many 3d objects on mapbox map using three.js

Tags: three.js, mapbox, vuejs3, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to add about 20.000 plane geometries on mapbox map. Docs have [example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-3d-model/) with only one object(even camera configured for one object).

My purpose - isometric buildings on map.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQTmU.png)

Threebox have very low performance and I have no idea about optimisation threebox objects

Comment: So, do you want to use mapbox or threeJS? Also, positioning the rest is setting other coordinates basically. No need for something special: loop on elements and position them on the plan.

Comment: Did you see example link? I want to render building on mapbox map using three.js

Comment: For me, you'll be faster using the map as a texture on a three JS plane.

Comment: I ran into this same issue and I did not find it easy to solve, probably due to lack of familiarity with 3D stuff.

Comment: I tried many different ways to solve this problem, is there another way to create isometric buildings using mapbox?